# AssertionError: Signal dimention should be of the format of (N,) but it is (743424, 2) instead

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, scipy

For my ML project, I'm using a Model to which I give a video and audio as input file to detect the synthetic voice in the video.

But it returns an error on the [audio_processing()](https://github.com/Neha13022020/Syncnet_model_VIDTIMIT_dataset/blob/main/deploy/app.py#L40) function:

**Code for audio_processing()**

```
def audio_processing(wav_file, verbose=True):

    rate, sig = wav.read(wav_file)
    if verbose:
        print("Sig length: {}, sample_rate: {}".format(len(sig), rate))

    try:
        mfcc_features = speechpy.feature.mfcc(sig, sampling_frequency=rate, frame_length=0.010, frame_stride=0.010)
    except IndexError:
        raise ValueError("ERROR: Index error occurred while extracting mfcc")

    if verbose:
        print("mfcc_features shape:", mfcc_features.shape)

    # Number of audio clips = len(mfcc_features) // length of each audio clip
    number_of_audio_clips = len(mfcc_features) // AUDIO_TIME_STEPS

    if verbose:
        print("Number of audio clips:", number_of_audio_clips)

    # Don't consider the first MFCC feature, only consider the next 12 (Checked in syncnet_demo.m)
    # Also, only consider AUDIO_TIME_STEPS*number_of_audio_clips features
    mfcc_features = mfcc_features[:AUDIO_TIME_STEPS*number_of_audio_clips, 1:]

    # Reshape mfcc_features from (x, 12) to (x//20, 12, 20, 1)
    mfcc_features = np.expand_dims(np.transpose(np.split(mfcc_features, number_of_audio_clips), (0, 2, 1)), axis=-1)

    if verbose:
        print("Final mfcc_features shape:", mfcc_features.shape)
    return mfcc_features
```

**Error:**

```
AssertionError: Signal dimention should be of the format of (N,) but it is (691200, 2) instead
```

```
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2548, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
File "D:\VU Final Project\4 - Final Deliverable\Synthetic-Speech-Detection-in-Video\app.py", line 673, in modelprediction
audio_fea = audio_processing(audio, False)
File "D:\VU Final Project\4 - Final Deliverable\Synthetic-Speech-Detection-in-Video\app.py", line 49, in audio_processing
mfcc_features = speechpy.feature.mfcc(
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\speechpy\feature.py", line 139, in mfcc
feature, energy = mfe(signal, sampling_frequency=sampling_frequency,
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\speechpy\feature.py", line 185, in mfe
frames = processing.stack_frames(
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\speechpy\processing.py", line 90, in stack_frames
assert sig.ndim == 1, s % str(sig.shape)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, your audio file contains two channels, which you can check by looking at the shape of the array that the `wav.read` function returns: `sig.shape`.

The `speechpy.feature.mfcc` function expects a single-channel audio.
I believe what you can do is to convert your audio to a single channel, for example by averaging the two channels:

```
sig = np.mean(sig, axis=1)
```

If you want your function to work on both single-channel and multi-channel data, you can just compute the mean only if the signal of your audio is multi-channel:

```
if sig.ndim == 2:
    sig = np.mean(sig, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. I have a question for you, if u could help me with that. I was looking for ML project to detect a sythentic voice in video e.g. model tells me either the video is tampered or not. I found this project (https://github.com/Neha13022020/Syncnet_model_VIDTIMIT_dataset), but when I give it a fake/real video with audio (I convert mp4 into wav file), it always tells me that the video is real/non-tampered, even when it's fake. Something I'm doing wrong with providing it input? and do u know of any open source project which solves this problem? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Stavrogin Unfortunately, I don't know any specifics about this project or any similar one, so I can't give you much advice. I see they have jupyter notebooks in the repository, so you can start by experimenting with those. Just make sure that you're feeding it the correct input and that you have loaded a pre-trained model.